# Grails Service injection fails when run on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am trying to deploy a small app that I developed using IntelliJ (Windows) on Tomcat 7 (CentOS 6). Everything runs on my development machine. I have run it using run-app and prod run-app.

My app has 1 controller that uses a Service (`def logService`). I have my service defined in the Service directory (`class LogService`). When run on my development system, logService in my controller is NOT null, but when I deploy it (using war file) logService is null.

Here is my controller:

```
package LogViewer

import grails.transaction.Transactional

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class OlrBrowserLogController
{
    def olrBrowserLogService

    def index() {
        def startDate = params.startDate

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance()
        if (startDate == null)
            now.add(Calendar.MONTH, -2)
        else {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('M/d/yyyy');
            now = sdf.parse(startDate).toCalendar()
        }

        def c = OlrBrowserLog.createCriteria()
        def rawLogEntries = c.list {
            gt("createdDate", now.getTime())
            order("createdDate", "desc")
        }

        def parsedLogEntries = []

        for (logEntry in rawLogEntries) {
            def parsedLogEntry = olrBrowserLogService.parseAgentString(logEntry)

            parsedLogEntries.add(parsedLogEntry)
        }

        return [parsedLogEntries: parsedLogEntries, startDate: now.getTime().format("M/d/y")]
    }
}
```

Here is my service:

```
package logviewer

import LogViewer.OlrBrowserLog
import LogViewer.bLog
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import net.sf.uadetector.ReadableUserAgent
import net.sf.uadetector.UserAgentStringParser
import net.sf.uadetector.service.UADetectorServiceFactory

@Transactional
class OlrBrowserLogService {
    def parseAgentString(OlrBrowserLog olrBrowserLogInstance)
    {
        // Get an UserAgentStringParser and analyze the requesting client
        UserAgentStringParser parser = UADetectorServiceFactory.getResourceModuleParser();
        ReadableUserAgent agent = parser.parse(olrBrowserLogInstance.browserUserAgent);

        def bLogInstance = new bLog()
        bLogInstance.userEmailAddress = olrBrowserLogInstance.wcUserEmailAddress
        bLogInstance.ipAddress = olrBrowserLogInstance.ipAddress
        bLogInstance.createdDate = olrBrowserLogInstance.createdDate.format("M/d/y h:mm a")
        bLogInstance.browserUserAgent = olrBrowserLogInstance.browserUserAgent
        bLogInstance.screenWidth = olrBrowserLogInstance.screenWidth
        bLogInstance.screenHeight = olrBrowserLogInstance.screenHeight
        bLogInstance.browserWidth = olrBrowserLogInstance.browserWidth
        bLogInstance.browserHeight = olrBrowserLogInstance.browserHeight
        bLogInstance.device = agent.deviceCategory.name
        bLogInstance.operatingSystem = agent.operatingSystem.name
        bLogInstance.browser = agent.name
        bLogInstance.version = agent.versionNumber.toVersionString()

        return bLogInstance
    }
}
```

I turned on some logging and I am getting this message:

> 2014-06-09 07:52:23,904 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] WARN  commons.GrailsApplicationFactoryBean  - Class with name [logviewer.OlrBrowserLogService] was not found, and hence not loaded. Possible empty class or script definition?

Comment: Service injection should work just fine in both cases.  Perhaps if you posted the relevant portions of your code, it would help others diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably much too late, but may be helpful for others:

I ran into the same problem after I did a renaming of a controller class - but I changed only one letter from upper- to lowercase. For some reason the compiler did not tidy up reliable and therefore the old class file remained in place. Because my development machine runs on Windows, this wasn't a problem there - but as soon as I deployed to a Linux machine I saw the same warning message:

```
"Class with name ["+className+"] was not found, and hence not loaded. Possible empty class or script definition?"
```

### The solution is trivial:

run `grails clean` to make sure everything gets re-compiled. Sometimes you have to delete the `target` directory too.

Probably you have a similar relict hanging around. And even more suspect is, that your service is in package `logviewer` but your controller is in `LogViewer` (and has no import of `logviewer.OlrBrowserLogService`). Correct this naming clutter, do a clean deployment and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause of this issue is that you are either missing a package declaration on `OlrBrowserLogService` or that the package definition does not match the directory structure. Verify your package is correct and try deploy again.

Comment: Thank you. I rechecked/redeployed everything and it still fails. I have updated my OP with all of the code from my controller and service. The controller is in controllers/LogViewer and the service is in services/logviewer.

Both of these files were initially created using the appropriate Grails command.

Comment: Any ideas about what might be going on or where to look for more information?